# Conditional sum over matrices in python/numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `X` and `W` each with shape `(N,N)` that result from the end of a calculation. Subdivide the range of `X` into equal intervals `[min(X), min(X)+delta, min(X)+2*delta,..., max(X)]`. I'd like to know, given an interval starting point `v`, the total of the corresponding `W` values:

```
idx = (X>=v) & (X<(v+delta))
W[idx].sum()
```

I need this sum for all starting intervals (ie. the entire range of `X`) and I need to do this for many different matrices `X` and `W`. Profiling has determined that this is the bottleneck. What I'm doing now amounts to:

```
W_total = []
for v0, v1 in zip(X, X[1:]):
    idx = (X>=x0) & (X<x1)
    W_total.append( W[idx].sum() )
```

How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.histogram()` to compute all those sums in a single operation:

```
sums, bins = numpy.histogram(
    X, bins=numpy.arange(X.min(), X.max(), delta), weights=W)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried numpy.histogram?

```
nbins = (X.max() - X.min()) / delta
W_total = np.histogram(X, weights=W, bins=nbins)
```